# How to iterate through a dictionary and check validity of inputs?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, python-3.5

how can I iterate over a dictionary and check input values for validity during the iterating loop? The problem is described in the code:

```
mydict ={'Kansas': 0, 'Dallas': 0, 'Alabama': 0} 

for key, value in mydict.items():
    inp = int(input('Your number for: ' + key))

    if inp > 0:
        value = inp
    else:
        print('enter again') #<---how can I jump back to the key
                             #    for which the entry was false
                             #    and ask again for the entry?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for key, value in mydict.items():
    while True:
        try:
            inp = int(input('Your number for: ' + key))
        except:
            inp = 0

        if inp > 0:
                mydict[keu] = inp
                break
        print('enter again')
```

Comment: I would add a try/except for `ValueError` in case the user enters a non-digit.

Answer (score 1):

```
mydict ={'Kansas': 0, 'Dallas': 0, 'Alabama': 0} 

for key, value in mydict.items():
    inp = int(input('Your number for: ' + key))
    while inp <= 0:
        inp = int(input('Enter again for: ' + key))
    value = inp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can interate just over `keys` instead if `items`. Try the following code:

```
my_dict = {'Kansas': 0, 'Dallas': 0, 'Alabama': 0} 

for key in my_dict.keys():
    inp = int(input('Your number for: {} '.format(key)))
    while inp <= 0:
        inp = int(input('Your number for: {} '.format(key)))
    my_dict[key] = inp
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to accomplish this, simply use the continue keyword.
The problem is that you are exhausting the dictionary.

Solution:

1. mydict ={'Kansas': 0, 'Dallas': 0, 'Alabama': 0}

   for key, value in mydict.items():    inp = -1
       while( inp = int(input('Your number for: ' + key)) == 0){pass}

   ```
   if inp > 0:
       value = inp
   ```